# Oracle Peoplesoft Case Expression error with date format

Tags: sql, oracle, expression, peoplesoft

Working in peoplesoft and keep getting the following error related to the expression below:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
>   expresssion:

```
CASE WHEN K.DUE_DT - K.PRIOR_DAYS >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN K.DUE_DATE
```

I did some googling and came up with this but I get the same error

```
(
    CASE  
        WHEN to_date(K.DUE_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  to_date(K.PRIOR_DAYS, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
            >= to_date(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        THEN  to_date(K.DUE_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    END
)
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and show the types of the relevant columns.

Comment: `to_date(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') ` - definitely don't do this. SYSDATE is already a date, TRUNCing it keeps it as a date; trying to TO_DATE a date will cause the date to be converted to a string (according to the default region settings of the DB) and so the string can be passed into the TO_DATE, then TO_DATE will try and convert it back, possibly fail. TLDR: never use TO_DATE on something that is already a date

Comment: What are the datatypes of columns `DUE_DT` and `PRIOR_DAYS`?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have:

```
WHEN to_date(K.DUE_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - to_date(K.PRIOR_DAYS, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= to_date(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Apart from what you've been told about applying `TO_DATE` function to something that already is date (i.e. `SYSDATE` in this case, maybe even `due_dt` and `prior_days` as well, if those are `DATE`s), here's how it goes: code you wrote means this:

- you are subtracting two dates (`due_dt - prior_days`)
- result of such an operation is **number** of days between those two dates
- you are then asking whether it is `>= sysdate` (i.e. **date**)

  - for example, that might be `when 4 > 2019-11-22 then ...`
- and that's why Oracle says `expected NUMBER got DATE`
- shortly, it doesn't make sense

Can it be fixed? Sure, only if we knew what you want to do. Hopefully, what I wrote will help you do it.

Comment: HI, that makes alot of sense, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Your comparision is wrong difference of dates gives a number of days not date so comparing a number with a date is pointless likewise Oracle gives the error